# What is the cleanest way to ssh and run multiple commands in Bash?

Tags: bash, unix, ssh

I already have an ssh agent set up, and I can run commands on an external server in Bash script doing stuff like:

```
ssh blah_server "ls; pwd;"
```

Now, what I'd really like to do is run a lot of long commands on an external server. Enclosing all of these in between quotation marks would be quite ugly, and I'd really rather avoid ssh'ing multiple times just to avoid this.

So, is there a way I can do this in one go enclosed in parentheses or something? I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
ssh blah_server (
   ls some_folder;
   ./someaction.sh;
   pwd;
)
```

Basically, I'll be happy with any solution as long as it's clean.

#### Edit

To clarify, I'm talking about this being part of a larger bash script. Other people might need to deal with the script down the line, so I'd like to keep it clean. I don't want to have a bash script with one line that looks like:

```
ssh blah_server "ls some_folder; ./someaction.sh 'some params'; pwd; ./some_other_action 'other params';"
```

because it is extremely ugly and difficult to read.

Comment: Hmm, how about putting all that into a script on the server and just calling it with one `ssh` invocation?

Comment: @Nikolai if the commands depends on the client side, they can be written into a shell script, then `scp`, `ssh`, and run. This will the cleanest way, I think.

Comment: This is part of a bigger bash script, so I'd rather not split it up with half living on my personal computer and the other half living on the server and run through ssh. If at all possible, I'd really like to just keep it as one script run from my personal computer. Is there really no clean way to encase a bunch of commands in an ssh?

Comment: Best way is not to use bash but Perl, Python, Ruby, etc.

Comment: *Why* do you want to avoid putting the remote commands in quotes?  You can have newlines inside the quotes, as many as you like; and using a string instead of standard input means standard input is available for e.g. reading input to the remote script.  (Though on Unix, single quotes are usually to be preferred over double quotes, unless you specifically need the local shell to evaluate some parts of the string.)

Comment: @khachik See the other answer how to run a script on the client side on the server.  e.g. 'ssh <remote-user>@<remote-host> "bash -s" <./remote-commands.sh -- arg1 arg2'. (not the answer to this question which asks how to do it with commands inline)

Answer (score 593, accepted):

How about a Bash [Here Document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
ssh otherhost << EOF
  ls some_folder; 
  ./someaction.sh 'some params'
  pwd
  ./some_other_action 'other params'
EOF
```

To avoid the problems mentioned by @Globalz in the comments, you may be able to (depending what you're doing on the remote site) get away with replacing the first line with

```
ssh otherhost /bin/bash << EOF
```

Note that you can do variable substitution in the Here document, but you may have to deal with quoting issues. For instance, if you quote the "limit string" (ie. `EOF` in the above), then you can't do variable substitutions. But without quoting the limit string, variables are substituted. For example, if you have defined `$NAME` above in your shell script, you could do

```
ssh otherhost /bin/bash << EOF
touch "/tmp/${NAME}"
EOF
```

and it would create a file on the destination `otherhost` with the name of whatever you'd assigned to `$NAME`. Other rules about shell script quoting also apply, but are too complicated to go into here.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want! How's it work? Would you happen to have a link to a page that explains it?

Comment: +1 Was just thinking that myself -- here's one place to read about it: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: When I use a heredoc like this the "Message of the Day" login is outputted to my local. Is there a way to silence this from displaying?

Comment: I also get this output to my local: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

Comment: It may be important for you to quote the *word* (i.e. first 'EOF') in order to prevent expansion of the command lines.  See:  man bash | less +/'Here Documents'

Comment: I wanted this tabbed in a script, by using <<- EOF it will consume the tabs, but note the last EOF must be on the same line.

Comment: I seemed to have to quote it all so I could pipe the output somewhere

like this
[code]
ssh piback "/bin/bash << EOF 
 lvcreate -L500M -s -n mailbackup /dev/cruz/mail >/dev/null
 mkdir -p /mnt/mail-backup
 mount -o ro,noload /dev/cruz/mailbackup /mnt/mail-backup
tar -czp /mnt/mail-backup
        umount /mnt/mail-backup
        lvremove -f /dev/cruz/mailbackup > /dev/null
EOF" | cat - > pibak-mail.tar.gz

Comment: comment system wouldn't let me format previous comment, so its a mess

Comment: @akc42 looks a lot like my remote backup script except I use `rsync with --link-dest` to keep multiple versions.

Comment: @PaulTomblin it is just like your script *except* to make it work I had to quote (with ") all the way from /bin/bash right through to the EOF at the end

Comment: For some reason "here document" didn't work for me. It was always existing after a particular command (may be that command is returning non zero exit code).  However this worked -  ssh $HOST 'ls ; pwd ; cmd3 ; cmd4'

Comment: It even worked when I used ~ for the home folder. It took the remote server users' home folder, just like I wanted.

Comment: When I use a 'sudo -S' command inside the EOF-brackets I'm not asked for my password (like I am when running a single SSH command in a script). How do we do this?

Comment: @Richard don't use `sudo -S` in a script. You should never put your password in a script, especially not if you have sudo privileges.

Comment: I don't put the password in the script. I type it in the terminal. But it doesn't work in heredocs

Comment: @Richard because you use `-S` which says to take the password from stdin rather than from the terminal.

Comment: You can also use something like `/bin/sh -e` instead of `/bin/bash` to exit immediately if any command fails.

Comment: Paul, I'm wondering if you might add a note about quoting here? Since heredocs don't know they're being used to control another shell, variables containing spaces or quotes could get dangerous. In really recent versions of bash it would be easiest to do e.g. `ssh <host> <<-EOF mv ${source@Q} ${dest@Q} EOF`. For older versions, variations on `printf '%q' "$myVariable"` should suffice.

Comment: @koyae the original question didn't include anything that needed special quoting. Let's not overcomplicate a seven-year-old question with detail that's interesting but not necessarily relevant.

Comment: Paul, I only suggest it because with nearly 200k views on this question, it looks like a lot of people are coming here when scripting with ssh. It's common to need to inject values when scripting. If not for the noise in the other questions and comments I would just make one and be on my way, but it's unlikely to be seen at this stage. A one-line footnote might save people some major headaches.

Comment: Please consider taking the "/bin/bash" to your standard answer and not offer it as optional as it does not work correctly without it. 
Thanx for the answer anyway.

Comment: I added the /bin/bash and variables work just fine, e.g. echo $NAME;

Comment: Is there a way to get the stdout and stdin of the remote server to your local terminal using this << EOF method?

Answer (score 154):

Edit your script locally, then pipe it into ssh, e.g.

```
cat commands-to-execute-remotely.sh | ssh blah_server
```

where `commands-to-execute-remotely.sh` looks like your list above:

```
ls some_folder
./someaction.sh
pwd;
```

Comment: This has the great advantage that you know **exactly** what is being executed by the remote script - no problems with quoting.  If you need dynamic commands, you can use a shell script with a subshell, still piping into the ssh, i.e. ``( echo $mycmd $myvar ; ...) | ssh myhost`` - as with the cat usage, you know exactly what is going into the ssh command stream.  And of course the subshell in the script can be multi-line for readability - see http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-sub-shells

Comment: Can you do this with arguments in the `commands-to-execute-remotely.sh`?

Comment: I think this is far more useful than paultomblin solution. Since the script can be redirected to any ssh server without having to open the file. Also it's far more readable.

Comment: yes, but using echo or a here document (see top answer) : use: `$localvar` to interpret a locally-defined variable, `\$remotevar` to interpret remotely a remotely-defined variable, `\$(something with optionnal args)` to get the output of something executed on the remote server. An exemple that you can ssh through 1 (or, like shown here, multiple ssh commands) : `echo " for remotedir in /*/${localprefix}* ; do cd \"\$remotedir\" && echo \"I am now in \$(pwd) on the remote server \$(hostname) \" ; done " | ssh user1@hop1 ssh user2@hop2 ssh user@finalserver bash `

Comment: Hmm...how is this different from using input redirection, i.e. `ssh blah_server < commands-to-execute-remotely.sh`?

Comment: Different approaches but in practice they do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 53):

To match your sample code, you can wrap your commands inside single or double qoutes. For example

```
ssh blah_server "
  ls
  pwd
"
```

Comment: I like this format, however it sadly is not useful for storing std data into a variable.

Comment: Signus, what do you mean by "storing std data into a variable"?

Comment: @Signus It is perfectly possible to do what you describe, although you will probably want to use single quotes instead of double quotes around the remote commands (or escape the operators which need to be escaped inside double quotes to prevent your local shell from intercepting and interpolating them).

Comment: I am not able to put inside double quotes code a command like this fileToRemove=$(find . -type f -name 'xxx.war'). fileToRemove should have a filename inside but instead it has an empty string. Does something need to be escaped?

Comment: @jkonst yes, the `$`.

Answer (score 46):

I see two ways:

First you make a control socket like this:

```
 ssh -oControlMaster=yes -oControlPath=~/.ssh/ssh-%r-%h-%p <yourip>
```

and run your commands

```
 ssh -oControlMaster=no -oControlPath=~/.ssh/ssh-%r-%h-%p <yourip> -t <yourcommand>
```

This way you can write an ssh command without actually reconnecting to the server.

The second would be to dynamically generate the script, `scp`ing it and running.

Answer (score 28):

This can also be done as follows.
Put your commands in a script, let's name it commands-inc.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ls some_folder
./someaction.sh
pwd
```

Save the file

Now run it on the remote server.

```
ssh user@remote 'bash -s' < /path/to/commands-inc.sh
```

Never failed for me.

Comment: Similar to what I was thinking originally! But why is `bash -s` needed?

Comment: Also, is `#!/bin/bash` really used?

Comment: The -s is there for compatibility.  
From man bash  

           -s        If  the -s option is present, or if no arguments remain after option processing, then commands are read from the standard input.
                 This option allows the positional parameters to be set when invoking an interactive shell.

Comment: But you are right, the  `#!/bin/bash` is not really needed. This was an example of running an existing local script on a remote server.

Comment: R J, thanks! With my first comment, it looks like we just do `ssh user@remote < /path/to/commands-inc.sh` (it seems to work for me). Well, I guess your version ensures we use the `bash` shell, and not some other shell - that's the purpose, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks. Yep, some of us have our notes, and habits from older versions of bash and other shells.  :-)

Comment: Not bad, but if you need variables/flags from the original script used within your ssh commands this is not useful unfortunately. It is clean though, if you dont need that.

Comment: @RJ not sure how its different to my answer :). Anyway
Cheers

Answer (score 16):

Put all the commands on to a script and it can be run like

```
ssh <remote-user>@<remote-host> "bash -s" <./remote-commands.sh
```

Comment: Somewhat odd but it works well. And args can be passed to the script (either before or after the redirect). e.g.  'ssh <remote-user>@<remote-host> "bash -s" arg1 <./remote-commands.sh arg2' e.g. 'ssh <remote-user>@<remote-host> "bash -s" -- -arg1 <./remote-commands.sh arg2'

Comment: I had a similar question with another answer above, but what is the purpose of including `bash -s`?

Comment: @flow2k -s is to indicate the bash to read the commands from standard input. Here is the description from the `man` pages
```If  the -s option is present, or if no arguments remain after
                 option processing, then commands are read from  the  standard
                 input.   This  option  allows the positional parameters to be
                 set when invoking an interactive shell.
```

Comment: @JaiPrakash Thanks for this, but I was actually thinking if we can just do away with the `bash` command altogether, i.e. `ssh remote-user@remote-host <./remote-commands.sh`. I tried my way and it seemed to work, though I'm not sure if it's deficient in some way.

Comment: @flow2k from my understanding of the man pages there wont be any deficiency without that option. Its required if you are trying to pass on any arguments. -- thanks

Comment: You cannot use flag variables & constants from your original script inside your remote-commands.sh ... :)

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if the cleanest for long commands but certainly the easiest:

```
ssh user@host "cmd1; cmd2; cmd3"
```

Comment: Best in simplicity!

Comment: This breaks down as soon as you need additional quoting in the remote command. Any dollar signs or backticks you need to pass through to the remote shell will need to be backslashed, or you will need additional quoting. Single quotes instead of double are a good solution for simpler quoting conundrums, but in this case tend to only push the problem to a different corner, as the remote shell will eat up one level of escaping.

Answer (score 11):

This works well for creating scripts, as you do not have to include other files:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh <my_user>@<my_host> "bash -s" << EOF
    # here you just type all your commmands, as you can see, i.e.
    touch /tmp/test1;
    touch /tmp/test2;
    touch /tmp/test3;
EOF

# you can use '$(which bash) -s' instead of my "bash -s" as well
# but bash is usually being found in a standard location
# so for easier memorizing it i leave that out
# since i dont fat-finger my $PATH that bad so it cant even find /bin/bash ..
```

Comment: The "$(which bash) -s" part gives you the location of bash on the local machine, rather than the remote machine.  I think you want '$(which bash) -s' instead (single-quotes to suppress local parameter substitution).

Comment: [Paul Tomblin provided the Bash Here Document](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4412338/608639) answer 6 years earlier. What value is added by this answer?

Comment: `-s` flag, I cite him *you may be able to get away with replacing the first line with...*, and I wasn't able to get away with just calling bash I dimly remember.

Answer (score 8):

**SSH and Run Multiple Commands in Bash.**

Separate commands with semicolons within a string, passed to echo, all piped into the ssh command.  For example:

```
echo "df -k;uname -a" | ssh 192.168.79.134

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       18274628 2546476  14799848  15% /
tmpfs             183620      72    183548   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1         297485   39074    243051  14% /boot
Linux newserv 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Nov 10 22:19:54 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: arnab, in the future, please describe what your code does briefly.  Then talk about how it works, then put in the code.  Then put the code in a code block so it's easy to read.

Comment: From the question, you offered *exactly* what the OP wants to avoid: *"I don't want to have a bash script with one line that looks like..."*

Answer (score 7):

For anyone stumbling over here like me - I had success with escaping the semicolon and the newline:

First step: the semicolon. This way, we do not break the ssh command:

```
ssh <host> echo test\;ls
                    ^ backslash!
```

Listed the remote hosts /home directory (logged in as root), whereas

```
ssh <host> echo test;ls
                    ^ NO backslash
```

listed the current working directory.

Next step: breaking up the line:

```
                      v another backslash!
ssh <host> echo test\;\
ls
```

This again listed the remote working directory - improved formatting:

```
ssh <host>\
  echo test\;\
  ls
```

If really nicer than here document or quotes around broken lines - well, not me to decide...

(Using bash, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.)

Comment: What's even better you can use && and || this way, too - echo test \&\& ls

Comment: @MiroKropacek That's nice, too. Better? Depends on what you want; run second command *conditionally*, then yes, run it *unconditionally* (no matter if first one succeeded or failed), then not...

Comment: @MiroKropacek, I didn't have to escape the && when putting double quotes around the commands: `ssh host "echo test && ls"`

Comment: Either quoting or backslashing is necessary but obviously not both, here (though there are situations where you do need to quote shell metacharacters from both the local and the remote shell).

Answer (score 7):

The posted answers using multiline strings and multiple bash scripts did not work for me.

- Long multiline strings are hard to maintain.
- Separate bash scripts do not maintain local variables.

Here is a functional way to ssh and run multiple commands while keeping local context.

```
LOCAL_VARIABLE=test

run_remote() {
    echo "$LOCAL_VARIABLE"
    ls some_folder; 
    ./someaction.sh 'some params'
    ./some_other_action 'other params'
}

ssh otherhost "$(set); run_remote"
```

Comment: You're thinking about this as if the only reason someone would want do to this is if they're sitting at a command line. There are other common reasons for this question as well, such as executing commands across distributed environments with tools such as rundeck, jenkins, etc.

Comment: @KamilCuk's answer is a (much!) better version of this, but more complex and hard to read and understand.

Answer (score 7):

For simple commands you can use:

```sh
ssh <ssh_args> command1 '&&' command2
```

or

```sh
ssh <ssh_args> command1 \&\& command2
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to configure your system to use single ssh sessions by default with multiplexing.

This can be done by creating a folder for the sockets:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh/controlmasters
```

And then adding the following to your .ssh configuration:

```
Host *
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/controlmasters/%r@%h:%p.socket
    ControlPersist 10m
```

Now, you do not need to modify any of your code. This allows multiple calls to ssh and scp without creating multiple sessions, which is useful when there needs to be more interaction between your local and remote machines.

Thanks to @terminus's answer, http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-osx-bsd-ssh-multiplexing-to-speed-up-ssh-connections/ and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing.

Answer (score 6):

> What is the cleanest way to ssh and run multiple commands in Bash?

I recommend using this escaping function. The function takes one argument - a function to escape. Then `sshqfunc` outputs `declare -f` of the function and then outputs a string that will call the function with `"$@"` arguments properly quoted. Then the whole is `"%q"` quoted and `bash -c` is added. In case the remote does not have bash, you could change bash to sh.

```
sshqfunc() { echo "bash -c $(printf "%q" "$(declare -f "$@"); $1 \"\$@\"")"; };
```

Then define a function with the work you want to do on the remote. The function is defined normally, so it will be properly "clean". You can test such function locally. After defining, properly escaped function is passed to the remote.

```
work() {
   ls
   pwd
   echo "Some other command"
}

ssh host@something "$(sshqfunc work)"
```

Passing You can also pass arguments, and they will be passed to your function as positional arguments. The right next argument after the function will be assigned to `$0` - usually a placeholder like `--` or `_` is used to separate arguments from call.

```
work() {
   file=$1
   num=$2
   ls "$file"
   echo "num is $num"
}

ssh host@something "$(sshqfunc work)" -- /this/file 5
```

But note that arguments should also be properly quoted if there are any magic characters:

```
ssh host@something "$(sshqfunc work)" -- "$(printf "%q" "$var1" "$var2")"
```

Comment: Good recommendations overall, but definitely not understandable or maintainable for people who are not well versed in Bash.