# trigger script on many remote machines

Tags: ssh, remote-access

How to trigger a script on many remote machines?

I have about Debian machines that have a script installed (it downloades data from dropbox). I have to trigger that script to run from remote at all machines at once (or one after another).

I've seen that you can run a script via [ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928116/write-a-shell-script-to-ssh-to-a-remote-machine-and-execute-commands) but I need to do it at 100 machines so loging in 100 times is rather not acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into MuSSH (http://sourceforge.net/projects/mussh/), Fabric or even salt, ansible etc...

Answer (score 0):

Setup a [Jenkins CI](http://jenkins-ci.org/)  instance.

1. Add all machines as build nodes and tag them (same tag for all nodes )
2. Configure one build job which executes your script and set the execution node to the chosen tag
3. Now you can easily add or remove nodes as well as changing the execution

Comment: quite interesting usage of jenkins