# how to prevent needing "npm rebuild" everytime with rsync and Node.js on Linux

Tags: linux, node.js

My deploy approach may be noob. I'm using rsync and it works for the most part on many node.js website except with certain ones where there are build dependancies for xml. I supposed I could try Git but was concerned with having bloat on the VMs and wanted to keep as lean as possible.

Is there a better way to do this using rsync options or should I try an alternative deployment approach. rcpy seems bad.

OR if I must "npm rebuild" then what is the command to do this if I created it in a shell script to automate this in terms of chaining commands?

UPDATE:

Using this approach:

[write a shell script to ssh to a remote machine and execute commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928116/write-a-shell-script-to-ssh-to-a-remote-machine-and-execute-commands)

with npm rebuild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run exactly the same node.js version on exactly the same processor architecture, you don't need `npm rebuild`, since your binaries will work on the target without a change.

Otherwise there is no way to avoid it (except for removing binary dependencies entirely of course).

Comment: Well in theory you can cross-compile to your target architecture and essentially run "npm rebuild" on your own computer instead of the servers. But I never did that.

Comment: yah i didn't understand packages at all. I get it now. I don't have to check node_modules into github at all. doh! (Homer Simpson reference).