# Launching SSH session via python script on raspberry pi

Tags: python, ssh, raspberry-pi2

I'm looking to create a script in python that initiates an SSH session with a server. I know it has to be a simple process i'm just not sure where to start. My ultimate plan is to automate this script to run on startup. i am not even sure python is the best way to go i just know it comes preloaded on raspbain for the pi.

Comment: This would be a one-liner in shellscript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a ssh connection with python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188970/how-to-make-a-ssh-connection-with-python)

Comment: @SufiyanGhori I disagree, while the subject might suggest it, the OP doesn't specifically ask about python.

Answer (score 2):

A simple bash script would be better suited to the task. It is possible with python, but there's no obvious reason to make it harder than necessary.

From
[write a shell script to ssh to a remote machine and execute commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928116/write-a-shell-script-to-ssh-to-a-remote-machine-and-execute-commands):

```
#!/bin/bash
USERNAME=someUser
HOSTS="host1 host2 host3"
SCRIPT="pwd; ls"
for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS} ; do
    ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${HOSTNAME} "${SCRIPT}"
done
```

From [how do i run a script at start up (askubuntu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228304/how-do-i-run-a-script-at-start-up):

> You will need root privileges for any the following. To get root, open
>   a terminal and run the command
>
> ```
> sudo su
> ```
>
> and the command prompt will change to '#' indicating that the terminal
>   session has root privileges.
>
> **Alternative #1.** Add an initscript.
>
> Create a new script in `/etc/init.d/myscript`.
>
> ```
> vi /etc/init.d/myscript
> ```
>
> (Obviously it doesn't have to be called "myscript".) In this script,
>   do whatever you want to do. Perhaps just run the script you mentioned.
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh 
> /path/to/my/script.sh
> ```
>
> Make it executable.
>
> ```
> chmod ugo+x /etc/init.d/myscript
> ```
>
> Configure the init system to run this script at startup.
>
> ```
> update-rc.d myscript defaults
> ```
>
> **Alternative #2.** Add commands to /etc/rc.local
>
> ```
> vi /etc/rc.local
> ```
>
> with content like the following.
>
> ```
> # This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel 
> /path/to/my/script.sh || exit 1   # Added by me 
> exit 0
> ```
>
> **Alternative #3.** Add an Upstart job.
>
> Create /etc/init/myjob.conf
>
> vi /etc/init/myjob.conf
>
> with content like the following
>
> ```
> description     "my job" 
> start on startup
> task
> exec /path/to/my/script.sh
> ```

Depending on what you do with the ssh connection, if it needs to stay open over the entire up time of the device, you will need to use some more trickery however (ssh connections are autoclosed after a period of inactivity).