# Errors in script for updating multiple machines through ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, apt

First, please forgive me for my inexperience.

I am trying to create a script that upgrades multiple machines through ssh, and I am receiving errors, primarily `"upgrade-all.sh: 7: Bad substitution"`

The original script that I am trying to modify mine from is found from Arjun G's answer from post [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928116/write-a-shell-script-to-ssh-to-a-remote-machine-and-execute-commands)

My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAMES="jed", "root", "cord"
HOSTS="***.***.***.***", "***.***.***.***", "***.***.***.***"
PASSWORDS="***", "***", "***"
SCRIPT="pwd; echo -e 'PASSWORD' | sudo apt update | sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y"
for i in ${!HOSTS[@]} ; do
        echo ${HOSTS[i]}
        SCR=${SCRIPT/PASSWORD/${PASSWORDS[i]}}
        sshpass -p ${PASSWORDS[i]} ssh -l ${USERNAMES[i]} ${HOSTS[i]} "${SCR}"
done
```

I tried swapping variables in `${!HOSTS[@]}`, but it did not clear up the error. I have found myself out of my depth to make educated guess with substitutions.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That's not how you create arrays in `bash`.

Comment: The original script you referenced shows the correct way to create arrays. Why did you change it?

Comment: You should have gotten an error on line 3 saying the `root,` is not a valid command.

Comment: Try [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to syntax check, and and the GNU [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) for array syntax.

Comment: And https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for how to use quotes and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization for how to name variables.

Comment: Also, from a security perspective, passing passwords on a command line is an _extremely_ bad idea. Much safer to pass them through environment variables, or on stdin, or otherwise to choose something that stops them from even momentarily showing up in `ps`.

Comment: [BashFAQ #5](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005) is another good general reference on array syntax and usage.

Comment: Maybe consider `ansible` which is designed for this kind of thing.

Comment: Whereas I (cc: @MarkSetchell) consider ansible horrid, but would encourage anyone to consider Chef. (Yes, it's Ruby; I have a deeply-seated distaste for Ruby, but I dislike having tools that aren't powerful enough for my use cases even more; as for ansible, its design isn't rigorous -- the configuration format has ambiguities that make some things impossible to represent -- and the agentless design makes for a _steep_ performance penalty). Mind, I consider ansible (and puppet, and saltstack, and other contemporaries) horrid, but not using _any_ orchestration tool is even worse.

Comment: (a good part of why tool selection is categorically off-topic here is flamewar deterrence; this is a place where folks tend to have strong opinions)

Comment: Since you already know the line number where the error occurs, it would be kind if you would show which line this is, instead of expecting us to count the lines manually.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same script, with bash syntax corrected (arrays creation) and basic array usage (mostly quoting).

I did not care any security issue (password on command-line), discussed on question comments.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

USERNAMES=("jed" "root" "cord")
HOSTS=("***.***.***.***" "***.***.***.***" "***.***.***.***")
PASSWORDS=("***" "***" "***")
SCRIPT="pwd; echo -e 'PASSWORD' | sudo apt update | sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y"
for i in "${!HOSTS[@]}" ; do
        echo "${HOSTS[i]}"
        SCR="${SCRIPT/PASSWORD/${PASSWORDS[i]}}"
        sshpass -p "${PASSWORDS[i]}" ssh -l "${USERNAMES[i]}" "${HOSTS[i]}" "${SCR}"
done
```