# Running multiple commands through ssh

Tags: bash

I am trying to run multiple commands using SSH but I am not getting my syntax right. Could someone please give me some help?

```
ssh "$USER"@"$IP" " \
    CURRENT_HOSTNAME=$(hostname); \
    sed -c -i 's/\($TARGET_KEY *= *\).*/\1$REPLACEMENT_VALUE/' $DISTRO_FILE; \
    sed -c -i 's/$CURRENT_HOSTNAME/$REPLACEMENT_VALUE/' $CONFIG_FILE; \
    hostname $REPLACEMENT_VALUE"
```

Those commands work fine if they are run locally, but I am getting the following error with when trying to run them through SSH:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

It seems the error comes from

```
sed -c -i 's/$CURRENT_HOSTNAME/$REPLACEMENT_VALUE/' $CONFIG_FILE; \
```

as it is trying to read $CURRENT_HOSTNAME which is set before in the SSH itself. I am not sure how to read that variable back. Any clue please?

EDITED the code:

```
ssh "$USER"@"$IP" "CURRENT_HOSTNAME=\$(hostname);
    sed -c -i \"s/\($TARGET_KEY *= *\).*/\1$REPLACEMENT_VALUE/\" $DISTRO_FILE;
    sed -c -i \"s/\$CURRENT_HOSTNAME/$REPLACEMENT_VALUE/\" $CONFIG_FILE;
    hostname $REPLACEMENT_VALUE"
```

This works! Thanks a lot!

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the cleanest way to ssh and run multiple commands in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4412238/608639)

Answer (score 3):

All variables with double quotes will be evaluated by Bash before sending the parameter to the remote machine.

If you want to preserve the `$variable` you will need to use single quotes instead (escaping single quotes within your commands), or escape all dollar signs you want evaluated on the server side.

You also don't need to escape line break and use semicolon. All line breaks will be included in the parameter.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I've made progress. I understand the idea now. I have an issue right now though because I have local variable (in the local bash script), one remote variable (the CURRENT_HOSTNAME) and sed complains for double quotes. I am updating the code above.

Comment: I got the code to work (solution up there in the edit). Thanks a lot Jonathan!