# Bash: Based on user input run all commands in a function on local OR on remote machine

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have a bash function which takes an array as an argument and it executes multiple commands.

Based on user input I want to run all the commands in this method locally or on remote machine. It has many quotes in the commands and echoing with "" will become ugly.

```
This is how I am invoking the function right now:
     run_tool_commands "${ARGS[@]}"

function run_tool_commands {
     ARGS=("$@")
     .. Loads of commands here
}

if [ case 1 ]; then 
  # run locally 
else 
  # run remotely
fi
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412238/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-ssh-and-run-multiple-commands-in-bash) seems helpful, but this is possible if I have the method text piped to "here document".

Comment: copy your script to remote machine using `scp`. Then login using `ssh` and run the script.

Comment: @sujin, which script? I just want to run a bunch of commands and unfortunately it doesn't look like I can separate them out to a script.

Comment: `login` over remote pc using `ssh` then you can run a all the commands .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If

1. all the commands that are to be executed under `run_tool_commands` are present on remote system as well,
2. All commands are executables, & not alias/functions
3. All these excutables are in default paths. (No need to source .bashrc or any other file on remote.)

Then perhaps this code may work: (not tested):

```
{ declare -f run_tool_commands; echo run_tool_commands "${ARGS[@]}"; } | ssh -t user@host
```

OR

```
{ declare -f run_tool_commands;
  echo -n run_tool_commands;
  for arg in "${ARGS[@]}"; do
      echo -ne "\"$t\" ";
  done; } | ssh -t user@host
```

Using for loop, to preserve quotes around arguments. (may or may not be required, not tested.)

Comment: With this approach a new ssh connection will be established for each command.