# Unable to run remote script on ubuntu using jenkins

Tags: linux, ssh, jenkins

I am trying to ssh to my deployment server to run a script using jenkins build server but it is giving error:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test/workspace
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson2847284723784326.sh
+ ssh user@serverIP
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Host key verification failed.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am using Execute shell build utility in jenkins. Steps used are:

1. ssh user@serverIP
2. cd pathofscript
3. ./script.sh

I can login manually in server without using password. I used this article to setup password less login : http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Kindly let me know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I think you need to send the commands to the remote server like in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412238/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-ssh-and-run-multiple-commands-in-bash

Comment: I tried 
ssh user@serverIP /path/test.sh

and it worked through my build machine but when I tried the same with jenkins it says:

Host key verification failed.

My builduser is different than jenkins. Do I need to generate ssh-keys for Jenkins also?

Comment: I think so, if you have root access then you can `su - jenkins` and generate the keys

Comment: Yes I logged in with jenkins user and followed the same link that I provided above and it resolved the issue. Thankyou for the help .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Jenkins [ssh plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin).