# Run Multiple Commands on Same SSH Session in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I would like to run several commands on one SSH session. For example, my script right now has something like the following:

```
ssh "machine A" do-thing-1
ssh "machine B" do-thing-2
ssh "machine A" do-thing-3
```

Having to SSH to A again in the third line is wasting a lot of time. How do I execute this without having to SSH again? Is this possible?

Comment: Is there any reason the code on machine B must run between thing 1 and thing 2 (that is, use `ssh "machine A" "do-thing-1; do-thing-3"; ssh "machine B" do-thing 2`). Otherwise, look at using the `-M` option when connecting to machine A so that the two logins to machine A can use the same socket (only the first needs to authenticate; the second can piggy-back over the original connection).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the cleanest way to ssh and run multiple commands in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4412238/608639)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `ssh` to A does not consume its standard input, you can easily make it wait for input.  Perhaps something like this.

```
ssh B 'sleep 5; do-thing-2; echo done.' | ssh A 'do-thing-1; read done; do-thing3'
```

The arbitrary `sleep` to allow `do-thing-1` to happen first is obviously a wart and a potential race condition.

A somewhat simpler and more robust solution is to use the ControlMaster feature to create a reusable `ssh` session instead.

```
cm=/tmp/cm-$UID-$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM
ssh -M -S "$cm" -N A &
session=$!
ssh -S "$cm" A do-thing-1
ssh          B do-thing-2
ssh -S "$cm" A do-thing-3
kill "$session"
wait "$session"
```

See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing for more.

Comment: Thanks. :D Is there not a nicer way to do this without any external tools, though? There are quite a few commands that happen at different times, and putting them all in the same statement would be hard to read.

Comment: For keeping multiple sessions open and communicating between them, I would be looking at Python+Paramiko or something like that instead for anything except the completely trivial case.  However, see also now the updated answer with the ControlMaster hack.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [screen](http://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/)

```
$: screen
$: do-thing-1

Ctrl-A and Ctrl-D exit this screen,

$: screen
$: do-thing-2

Ctrl-A and Ctrl-D exit this screen,

$: screen
$: do-thing-2

Ctrl-A and Ctrl-D exit this screen,

view all `screen`, 
$: screen -ls

Restore screen by id,

$: screen -r <Screen ID>
```