# Jenkins SSH shell closes before executing remote commands

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I have a Jenkins job with the following commands under "Execute shell":

```
ssh jenkins@172.31.12.58
pwd
```

I want the Jenkins server to connect via SSH to the remote server then run a command on the remote server.

Instead, Jenkins connects to the remote server, disconnects immediately, then runs the `pwd` command locally as can be seen in the output:

```
Started by user Johanan Lieberman
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Test Github build/workspace
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson266272646442487328.sh
+ ssh jenkins@172.31.12.58
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
+ pwd
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Test Github build/workspace
Finished: SUCCESS
```

**Edit**: Any idea why the subsequent commands after the `ssh` command aren't run inside the SSH shell, but rather run locally instead?

Comment: Potential duplicate: [What's the Cleanest Way to SSH and Run Multiple Commands in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4412238/172599)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're not running interactively, SSH does not create an interactive session (thus the "Pseudo-terminal" error message you see), so it's not quite the same as executing a sequence of commands in an interactive terminal.

To run a specific command through an SSH session, use:

```
ssh jenkins@YOUR_IP 'uname -a'
```

The remote command must be quoted properly as a single argument to the ssh command. Or use the [bash here-doc syntax](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) for a simple multi-line script:

```
ssh jenkins@YOUR_IP <<EOF
pwd
uname -a
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks @Dave, this is the explanation I was looking for.

Comment: Adding `EOF` at the end of remote shell commands gives me `-bash: line 2: EOF: command not found`. After removing this line everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the [Publish Over SSH plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) to execute commands on a slave with SSH:

[image]

If the Source files field is mandatory, maybe you can transfer a dummy file.

Update:
Another solution is to use the [SSH plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin). Maybe it's a better solution compare to the other plugin :)

Comment: This is a good workaround, however I wanted to know the reason I couldn't accomplish this using the "Execute shell" option. I know it should work that way too.

Comment: Did you have a look to this plugin? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin

Comment: No. My point was to understand why I couldn't open an SSH shell, then run commands inside it the way I described in the original post. I already managed to get it working using your first plugin.

Comment: OK cool if it works with the first plugin, don't forget to validate my solution ;)