# Linux SSH with multiple commands

Tags: linux, ssh, command

i want to make an ssh-connect to an remote host, there i want to run multiple commands.

```
ssh -l blabla 123.123.123.123 ls -l
```

when i run this, i will get the result of `ls -l on 123.123...`

Is it possible, to make sth like this:

```
ssh -l blabla 123.123.123.123 ls -l & ifconfig
```

... it tried this:

```
ssh -l blabla 123.123.123.123 ls -l; ifconfig
```

But there the local bash runs the second command.
I want the second command to run on the remote host.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to quote the `&` and `;` characters like this: `ssh user@host ls -l \; ifconfig`

Comment: ``ssh user@host 'command1; command2; command3'``

Comment: Both doesn't work. With \; the ; is converted to an normal character. And with "...;..." it's the same result: both commands are one command. The remote server tries to execute:  >>ls -l \ ifconfig<< or >>ls -l; ifconfig<<

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the cleanest way to ssh and run multiple commands in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4412238/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put all commands inside a quotes

```
ssh afont@123.123.123.123 "ls -l; ifconfig;"
```

Comment: _Thank you, but the same problem as in the commends over your answer:_  Both doesn't work. With \; the ; is converted to an normal character. And with "...;..." it's the same result: both commands are one command. The remote server tries to execute: >>ls -l \ ifconfig<< or >>ls -l; ifconfig<<

Comment: If this isn't working, perhaps you have an alias for `ssh` that is mangling the arguments.  Try `type ssh`.

Comment: ah i  found the Problem, it works Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should try using "-t" before the commands:

```
ssh UserName@HostNameOrIP -t 'comand1 && command2'
```