# Executing pipe or for loop in bash -c over ssh in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: bash, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

### Intro

I am writing a bash script that is being executed from Jenkins Pipeline. Groovy DSL is not a problem for me, I am using bare shell commands.

For every command so far I have been using `bash -c` and passed over commands I wanted, like below:

```
ssh -l <user> <host> bash -c "'
     cd /my/path
     ./script.sh param1 param2
     echo $MY_VAR
'"
```

**That works great.**

---

### The problem

Now I had a more complicated command:

```
ls -1t | egrep 'regexp' | tail -n +10 | xargs rm -rf
```

Basically listing some directory and deleting all items but for last 10. It works using in `bash` but it does not with `bash -c`.

I also tried a *for-loop* version:

```
for f in $(ls -1t | egrep 'regexp' | tail -n +10); do rm -rf $f; done;
```

But it does not work either.
I get an error, like:

```
bash: line 4:
  for f in <actual_item1> <actual_item2> <actual_item3>; do echo <actual_item1>; done;
       No such file or directory
```

So there is some issue with `$` variable resolution. How to overcome this?
Or how do I make the *piped* version work?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the actual ssh command that you're running with quotes and variable references intact. This probably just a matter of getting your quotes right.

Comment: it was not the quotes. `bash -c` does not work when passing this pipe (I do not know why), but passing `<< EOF` helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out **it is** partially Jenkins groovy DSL issue, but with help of

- [anubhava answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46445430/1549135)
- [darvark answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46445446/1549135)
- [What is the cleanest way to ssh and run multiple commands in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412238/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-ssh-and-run-multiple-commands-in-bash)

I managed to find my way around it.

#### The solution

```
    sh("""ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l <user> <host> /bin/bash << EOF
        cd /my/dir/;
        ls -1t | egrep 'regexp' | tail -n +10 | xargs rm -rf;
EOF""")
```

#### Comment

The usage of `sh` plugin is pretty straight-forward.

The trick is to pass `EOF` to `/bin/bash`, and the **LAST** line of the script (containing `EOF`) **MUST NOT** contain any other char.
Even **indention** may cause problems, so simply remove all chars - that is why it is not "nicely" aligned.

Then it works. Thanks a lot, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You can use here-doc with `ssh` command to run one or more commands:

```
ssh $user@$hostname bash -s<<-'EOF'
ls -1t | egrep 'regexp' | tail -n +10 | xargs rm -rf
EOF
```

It is however not recommended to parse `ls` command's output, better use `find ... -print0` like this:

```
ssh $user@$hostname bash -s<<-'EOF'
find . -regex '.*regexp' -print0 | tail -zn +10 | xargs -0 rm -rf
EOF
```

Comment: This will use my default shell (`ksh`) on the server, so I need to specify the shell.

Comment: ok `bash -s` should take care of that. Try my updated answer now.

Comment: Why do you any shell for this? `ssh $user@$hostname "find . -regex '.*regexp' -print0 | tail -zn +10 | xargs -0 rm -rf"`.

Comment: Yes @chepner, for these commands `bash` is not needed. Since OP asked specifically to be able to run `bash` I assumed OP is running some more `bash` specific commands on remote host.

Answer (score 1):

At first you dont have to provide +10 to tail -n. by default it takes last 10 lines, if you want use first 10 lines, use head.  why do you want use bash -c, it should work if you just provide this command to ssh, or check [What is the cleanest way to ssh and run multiple commands in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412238/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-ssh-and-run-multiple-commands-in-bash)

Comment: I need to provide `bash -c` because by default there is `ksh` and scripts do not work.

Answer (score 0):

For example you have a list of ip addresses in txt file and you want to check amount of java processes on each box writing ip address right after amount of processes . You can do the following :

`cat ipv4.txt | xargs -I IP sh -c 'ssh username@IP  "ps aux | grep java | grep -v grep | wc -l   " && echo IP'`

Inline your command and have fun.