# bash script for ssh connect and change folder

Tags: bash

There is the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit

# Общие параметры
server="some_server"
login="admin"
default_path="/home/admin/web/"
html_folder="/public_html"

# Параметры проекта
project_folder="project_name"

go_to_folder() {
  ssh "$login@$server"
  cd "/home/admin/web/"
}

go_to_folder
```

I got error "deploy.sh: line 16: cd: /home/admin/web/: No such file or directory", but if I connect manually and change directory through "cd" it works. How can I change my script?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the cleanest way to ssh and run multiple commands in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4412238/3776858)

Comment: Did the answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is obvious, didn't it? You are trying to do `cd` to the local machine and *not* on the target machine. The commands to be passed to `ssh` much be provided in-line with its parameters, on a separate newline its looking as if you are doing no-op on the remote machine and running the `cd` in the local.

```
go_to_folder() {
ssh "$login@$server" "cd /home/admin/web/"      
}
```

Or a more cleaner way to do would be to use here-docs

```
go_to_folder() {
ssh "$login@$server" <<EOF
cd /home/admin/web/
EOF
}
```

other ways to make `ssh` read from stanard input on the commands to run would be to use here-strings(`<<<`) also.