# Get PID of a remote process started with sshpass

Tags: linux, pid, nohup, sshpass

I have a bash script which need to start some process on remote machine.
I have done that using `sshpass` command.

I need to store the PID of that remote process.

I tried the following with a script:

`sshpass -p password ssh user@ipaddr /bin/bash << EOF
nohup process > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > pid_file
cat pid_file
EOF`

when I check with remote machine, the process is started and pid_file also has a number written in it. But the process id and number of pid_file do not match.

Executing the above set of commands directly on terminal without script, doesn't write anything in pid_file.

Can somebody help in storing the right pid of remote process.

Comment: maybe executing `nohup process 2&1>pid_file` would give you more info.

Comment: Its stuck this ways. I have to run the process "iperf3" in background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sshpass -p password ssh user@ipaddr /bin/bash << EOF
nohup process > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > pid_file
cat pid_file
EOF
```

The thing is that `$!` get's expanded not on the remote computer, but on your computer. When using the [Here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells), variable names are replaced by their values. So it gets expanded to whatever process you have had run in the background on you computer. You need to execute `echo $!` on the remote computer. That's why it's good to use `-c` and to always properly enclose the arguments.

```
sshpass -p password ssh user@ipaddr /bin/bash -c 'nohup process >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > pid_file'
```

or you can just escape the `$!`:

```
sshpass -p password ssh user@ipaddr /bin/bash <<EOF
nohup process > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo \$! > pid_file
cat pid_file
EOF
```

or the best is to use quoted here string delimiter:

```
sshpass -p password ssh user@ipaddr /bin/bash <<'EOF'
nohup process > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > pid_file
cat pid_file
EOF
```

Comment: Yes Bingo. Thanks Kamil. This escape character really helped. I cannot use `-c` option as there are some more verification required before executing the command. But one more issue is that `cat pid_file` is not getting saved in a variable. I did `var=$(cat pid_file)` but `echo $var` gives blank. What could be the reason of it?

Comment: Everything you can do with here document or here string can be done with passing `-c` options to bash. Maybe try first saving the command string to a file, and then pass it to bash, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464983/9072753). It's way cleaner that way. Also you can inspect the file for errors.