# Automate feeding the output of a command to a prompt

Tags: bash, icinga, icinga2

I have a script that reads a text file that has all the nodes listed in there:

```
node1
node2
node3
.
.
.
```

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read f; do
   ssh-copy-id myusername@"$f"
   ssh username@master.icinga.test.com
   icinga2 pki ticket --cn '$f' 
done < linux-list.txt

while read f; do
   ssh myusername@"$f" '
        yum install -y epel-release
        wget --no-check-certificate https://packages.icinga.org/epel/7/release/noarch/icinga-rpm-release-7-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
        yum install icinga-rpm-release-7-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
        yum install -y icinga2  nagios-plugins-all
        chown -R icinga:icinga /etc/icinga2  /var/lib/icinga2 /var/log/icinga2' </dev/null
   ssh myusername@master.icinga.test.com icinga2 pki ticket --cn "$f" |
   ssh myusername@"$f" 'cat >/tmp/pkicode'
   scp ./zones.conf myusername@"$f":/etc/icinga2/zones.conf
done < linux-list.txt
```

1) The script should log into the Icinga master and run a command `icinga2 pki ticket --cn '$f'` for each node found on that `linux-list.txt` file and generate a ticket for each host

2) Then sends this generated code to each node ($f)

After going through all the commands above, then the script needs to run a command icinga2 node wizard which will start a question/answer prompt and needs someone to type the answer as shown below.

Icinga master's FQDN is `master.icinga.test.com` and it's IP is `10.20.20.1`. The PKI ticket is what we generated earlier on the Icinga master and it's different for each host.

Is there any way to automate this?

```
Y
Enter
master.icinga.test.com
Y
10.20.20.1
N
Y
[PKI Ticket created earlier on the Icinga master]
Enter
Enter
Y
Y
Enter
Enter
N
N
```

Thanks

Comment: Wizards are meant for humans, not for computers. Check whether your tool has a scriptable interface.

Comment: https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/11-cli-commands/#cli-command-node vaguely suggests you should be using `node setup` instead of `node wizard` in scripts.

Comment: `'$f'` in single quotes just produces the literal string `$f`. To interpolate the value of the variable `f`, use double quotes. But this command should not be in the first loop anyway; you have it vaguely correct in the second loop already.

Comment: If you do both things in the same script, there is no need for two loops, anyhow; just move `ssh-copy-id` to the beginning of the second loop and get rid of the first. The reason I suggested to do them separately is to be able to run the parts which don't require user interaction unattended, in parallel, from another script, etc.

Comment: (For reference, the previous question in this saga is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525313/how-to-ssh-to-remote-hosts-and-run-multiple-commands)

Comment: @tripleee
Thank you for your advice. How will the icinga2 daemon get that pki ticket we generated on the server?

Comment: https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/06-distributed-monitoring/#distributed-monitoring-automation has the specific example `icinga2 node setup --ticket ead2d570e18c78abf285d6b85524970a0f69c22d --cn icinga2-client1.localdomain --endpoint icinga2-master1.localdomain --zone icinga2-client1.localdomain --parent_zone master --parent_host icinga2-master1.localdomain --trustedcert /var/lib/icinga2/certs/trusted-parent.crt --accept-commands --accept-config --disable-confd`

Comment: If reading documentation is not a strength of yours, again, maybe posting a separate question about just this specific problem may be a better use of both your own time and mine.

Comment: @tripleee, sure, I created a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564830/how-to-use-heredoc-to-answers-prompt-questions
Thank you so much for all your help

Answer (score 0):

in the future, try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because that was too long to read.

However, it looks like you just want to pipe a series of inputs to a prompt. You can do this with a `heredoc`, like so

```
PKI="some text whatever ticket thing blahblahblah"
somecmd << EOF
Y
Enter
master.icinga.test.com
Y
10.20.20.1
N
Y
$PKI
Enter
Enter
Y
Y
Enter
Enter
N
N
EOF
```

`heredoc`s can do variable expansion. cool.

Comment: Thanks, so I should create a file (i.e. answers.txt) and then call it after 'icinga2 pki ticket --cn '$f' ' command? Can you elaborate on that more please? Thanks

Comment: No, this is a complete answer. Maybe google [here document.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)

Comment: @IrinaI, please see tripleee's comment

Comment: For some reason my previous comment is not showing up, where will I add the heredoc? I am Googling it but still not clear how the while loop and icinga installation will be connected to the heredoc.