# Why does this not kill remote process?

Tags: linux, remote-access, kill-process

The follow command works in a local terminal:

```
ps aux | grep "script.py" | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill -2
```

But this command doesn't work remotely:

```
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=6 john@remote-pc ps aux | grep "script.py" | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill -2
```

...even though script.py on remote belongs to john, the user we are ssh as.  I can ping successfully and other commands are successful.

Comment: Only `ps aux` is running on the remote machine the rest is running on the local machine

Comment: If I delete the final `xargs kill -2` then I still receive the print of the remote pid so I'm not sure you're correct.

Comment: Why? If ps returns the correct string from the remote machine running grep and awk on the local machine will work correctly

Comment: Ohhhhh, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the pipes to cause them to be passed to the `ssh` command rather than being executed by your local shell otherwise everything after `ps aux` is executed on your local machine.

```
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=6 john@remote-pc ps aux \| grep "script.py" \| awk {\'print $2\'} \| xargs kill -2
```

Comment: Thanks that's great to know. In fact I discovered it was also necessary to escape the single quotes in the `awk` command when executed remotely.

Comment: @JSStuball yep, getting this right is tricky, for anything other than simple commands I tend to write a shell script instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412238/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-ssh-and-run-multiple-commands-in-bash