# Adding the hostname of a remote server to a formatted ssh command response

Tags: awk, ssh, hostname

If i run this command directly (via ssh terminal) on a remote REHL server:
`w -uh | awk -vhostname="$(hostname)" '{print "On "hostname ,$1,"is connected with IP: "$3}`'

I get an output like this:

> *On remote.server1.address.com accountname is connected with IP: 8.8.8.8*

However if i run this command remotely via SSH commands in a script (to check multiple servers):
`ssh account@remote.server.address.com w -uh | awk -vhostname="$(hostname)" '{print "On "hostname ,$1,"is connected with IP: "$3}`'

The result of the command gives the local machine hostname instead of the remote server:

> On local.machine.address.com accountname is connected with IP: 8.8.8.8
>
> On local.machine.address.com accountname is connected with IP: 0.0.0.0
>
> On local.machine.address.com accountname is connected with IP:255.255.255.255*

I'm looking for a result like below.

> On remote.server1.address.com accountname is connected with IP: 8.8.8.8
>
> On remote.server2.address.com accountname is connected with IP: 0.0.0.0
>
> On remote.server3.address.com accountname is connected with IP:255.255.255.255*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the cleanest way to ssh and run multiple commands in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412238/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-ssh-and-run-multiple-commands-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because the command `hostname` is running on your local machine. You need to pass the entire command in quotes like:

```
ssh account@remote.server.address.com "w -uh | awk -v hostname=\$(hostname) '{print \"On \"hostname ,\$1,\"is connected with IP: \"\$3}'"
```