# Bash script to ping through an ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

The script I want to use is the one below. The issues is finding a way to run pings from the device that I have connected to in the bash script.. The ssh is opened by running a script, and I don't have direct access to the ssh info. The script calls for me to put in my creds to connect. I appreciate any help.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Ol mnqnzf
echo "Enter the alarm ticket contents."
pluma Contents
cat Contents | grep -E -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)" > ipfound
for IP in $(cat ipfound);
do
        ping -c 5 $IP
        echo ""
done
rm ipfound
rm Contents
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You don't mention what happens when you run your script, or how it's different from what you expected. Is it safe to assume that the behavior you're seeing is "The script asks me to put my creds in. I do so, and it gives me a remote shell and nothing else happens. When I log out with `exit`, the script starts pinging from my local machine. I wanted it to ping from the remote host instead, without giving me a shell"?

Comment: What  does `ssh-instance cta` do?

Comment: @the other guy
The current script format doesn't work as it will ping on the local network, instead of running the ping command on the ssh.

Comment: @Cyrus That script is used to open up a ssh connection to a remote system. I do not have details on the exact scripting. It will prompt me for my creds, and then finish opening the ssh connection.

Comment: So basically I removed the notation about ssh-instance.  I guess the really question is I just need to figure out how to make the script run locally, except run the ping on the ssh device.

Comment: You can read all about passing commands to ssh and similar tools in the duplicate, and a further example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412238/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-ssh-and-run-multiple-commands-in-bash). Keep in mind that your file is created on the local machine, so you either have to include its contents or create it on the server

Comment: @thatotherguy Not sore what I am getting hung up on. 

`code
#!/bin/bash
ssh me@server.com <<EOF
echo "0"
ping 10.10.10.10
echo "1"
EOF
`
+ ssh me@server.com
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
me@server.com's password: "I enter the password then bet the following"
0

Comment: You're saying there's no output from ping at all?

Comment: @thatotherguy When I put in that code above it never even reaches the ping. It asks for my password I put that in, and then it ends up sitting at a blank line no prompt. It must have something to do with that error "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal" I think

Comment: The system I am using is based of CentOS.

Comment: @RonaldTidwell The message would generally be harmless, but you can use `ssh -tt` to allocate a pty anyways

Comment: So what would be causing it to not get a ssh prompt so the rest of the command can run?