# Im trying to get variable that is in a here document (EOF) to echo or store in the script outside the EOF

Tags: shell

Im writing a script the i add later as a cronjob, so this script has functions and inside it uses a here document to execute commands on remote server

there is a variabe "result" in this script that will tel the state of the hosts

I need the same variable "result" to echo outside of the here document (EOF)

How do i do this

```
one(){
ssh_cmd="$(cat <<-EOF

        echo --------------------------------------------------------------
        echo "Checking testapp Status on Domain Controller --> host = slave1 "
        echo --------------------------------------------------------------

        result=(\$(/opt/jboss/web/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect controller=10.0.0.4:9990 --commands='ls /host=slave1/server-config=testapp' | grep 'status=' | awk 'FNR%2' | sed -r 's/.{7}//'))

        echo ----------------
        echo "\${result[@]}"
        echo ----------------

        if [ "\${result[@]}" != "STARTED" ];
        then
                echo --------------------------------------
                echo "Starting the server"
                echo --------------------------------------

                /opt/jboss/web/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect controller=10.0.0.4:9990 --commands='/host=slave1/server-config=testapp:start'
        else
                echo --------------------------------------
                echo "Server is running"
                echo --------------------------------------
        fi

EOF
)"
ssh -t root@someserver "$ssh_cmd"
}

echo $result

if [ $result == value];
then
  two (run function two)
else
exit
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68359474/9072753 might be of use for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> need the same variable "result" to echo outside of the here document (EOF)

Then you need to send it, no other way. You could send it using the output of `ssh`:

```
     ....
     # output the value.
     echo "unique_string_with_result=$result"
EOF
)"
    # get ssh output to a file
    ssh ..... | tee tempfile.txt
    # filter the output and extract the value
    result=$(sed -n 's/unique_string_with_result=//p' tempfile.txt)
}
```

Comment: I thought so, was hoping there was some way to do it without creating a file on the remote server, but thank you.

Comment: `without creating a file on the remote server` The code I presented above does not create a file on the remove server. It creates a file on the local workstation. Still, you can use a `var=$(ssh .... | tee /dev/stderr);`  variable as a temporary location of output, with proper `tee` redirection.

Comment: Thanks i misunderstood :)