# bash dealing with multiple quotation

Tags: string, bash

From a bash terminal, I want to log-in to a computing node and execute some command, for example, I do this to check the running jobs

```
ssh -t node1 'top -bn1 | grep R | grep -v top'
```

This logins to `node1` and runs the `top` command and grep desired output.
Now I want to check the memory load of the node. I have taken this code from here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119126/command-to-display-memory-usage-disk-usage-and-cpu-load

```
free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }'
```

Now, I can not just do

```
ssh -t node1 '<above command>'
```

as there are multiple quote that will affect the command. Is there a way to execute the above command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use here-doc to avoid quoting issues :

```
ssh node1 << 'EOF'
free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }'
EOF
```

Notice quotes around EOF so as to pass content as is.

We don't usually use `-t` of ssh if we just run commands directly

Comment: This is nice and works but it shows `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` every time I runs it. Can it be made silent.

Comment: So, I use `-T` to silent the warning.

Answer (score 1):

For instance with

```
ssh -t node1 'free -m | '"awk 'NR==2"'{printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }'
```

The idea here is to put the string together in pieces. When you have a sequence containing a single quote, wrap it into double quotes. The parts containing a variable expansion or a double quote gets wrapped between single quotes.

Comment: I think this is missing a final double-quoted single-quote. The easy way to check is by replacing the `ssh -t node1` part with `echo`, since that'll print its arguments after the (local) shell has applied and removed the first layer of quotes, so the output matches what the remote shell will see and execute. (Well, unless your version of `echo` does its own escape interpretation, in which case it can just add another level of confusion. But that's not an issue here, because there aren't any escapes involved.)

Answer (score 0):

Your command contains single quotes, so you cannot pass this command to `ssh` as a single-quoted string (single quotes cannot be escaped within single quotes).

Therefore, your options are as follows:

1. Either remove the single quotes from the command and change it so that it uses only double quotes.
2. ...or pass the command to `ssh` in *double* quotes (`ssh -t node1 "<above command>"`). You will then need to escape special characters in `<above command>` (like `$` or other double quotes) to prevent local expansion.

In your particular case, you can also work around this issue by not running `awk` on the remote side, but running it locally instead. So this will work:

```
ssh -t node1 'free -m' | awk 'NR==2{printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }'
```

In many cases this leads to a simpler and more readable solution. (However, you need to be aware that if you process remote data locally, then all remote data is transferred through ssh first -- so don't do this when you need to grep tons of data).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to execute the above command?

First define a function with the commands you want to execute. Write normal well-formatted readable code, just in a function. Remember to use shellcheck to check for common mistakes.

```
f() {
    free -m |
    awk '
        NR==2 {
         printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)\n", $3, $2, $3 * 100 / $2 
       }
    '
}
```

Then you will need a simple small function escaping function, that I also posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412238/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-ssh-and-run-multiple-commands-in-bash/68359474#68359474):

```
sshqfunc() { echo "bash -c $(printf "%q" "$(declare -f "$1"); $1 \"\$@\"")"; };
```

Then just:

```
ssh -t node1 "$(sshqfunc f)"
```