# How to run a script on server from local machine?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I am trying to compress my folder, send it to the server, and decompress it. I set up the `ssh-keygen` so that scp and ssh works without password. However, once the `ssh user@server` line is executed, the remaining lines are not executed since the control is transferred to the server. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I am not sure how to make this as a minimum-reproducible example.

```
tar -czvf targetfolder.tar.gz targetfolder
echo "zipped targetfolder; moving to server"
scp targetfolder.tar.gz user@server:
ssh user@server
cd ~/targetfolderonserver
rm -rf targetfolder
mv ~/targetfolder.tar.gz ./
tar -xf targetfolder.tar.gz
```

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412238/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-ssh-and-run-multiple-commands-in-bash

Comment: Yes!! thanks, I will delete my question!