# Trying to embed newline in a variable in Bash

Tags: bash

I have

```
var="a b c"
for i in $var
do
   p=`echo -e $p'\n'$i`
done
echo $p
```

I want the last *echo* to print:

```
a
b
c
```

Notice that I want the variable *p* to contain newlines. How do I do that?

Answer (score 252, accepted):

## Summary

1. Inserting a new line in the source code

   ```
    p="${var1}
    ${var2}"
    echo "${p}"
   ```
2. Using `$'\n'` (only [Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) and [Z shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zsh))

   ```
    p="${var1}"$'\n'"${var2}"
    echo "${p}"
   ```
3. Using `echo -e` to convert `\n` to a new line

   ```
    p="${var1}\n${var2}"
    echo -e "${p}"
   ```

## Details

1. Inserting a new line in the source code

   ```
    var="a b c"
    for i in $var
    do
       p="$p
    $i"       # New line directly in the source code
    done
    echo "$p" # Double quotes required
              # But -e not required
   ```

   Avoid extra leading newline

   ```
    var="a b c"
    first_loop=1
    for i in $var
    do
       (( $first_loop )) &&  # "((...))" is Bash specific
       p="$i"            ||  # First -> Set
       p="$p
    $i"                      # After -> Append
       unset first_loop
    done
    echo "$p"                # No need -e
   ```

   Using a function

   ```
    embed_newline()
    {
       local p="$1"
       shift
       for i in "$@"
       do
          p="$p
    $i"                      # Append
       done
       echo "$p"             # No need -e
    }

    var="a b c"
    p=$( embed_newline $var )  # Do not use double quotes "$var"
    echo "$p"
   ```
2. Using `$'\n'` (less portable)

   [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) interprets `$'\n'` as a new line.

   ```
    var="a b c"
    for i in $var
    do
       p="$p"$'\n'"$i"
    done
    echo "$p" # Double quotes required
              # But -e not required
   ```

   Avoid extra leading newline

   ```
    var="a b c"
    first_loop=1
    for i in $var
    do
       (( $first_loop )) &&  # "((...))" is bash specific
       p="$i"            ||  # First -> Set
       p="$p"$'\n'"$i"       # After -> Append
       unset first_loop
    done
    echo "$p"                # No need -e
   ```

   Using a function

   ```
    embed_newline()
    {
       local p="$1"
       shift
       for i in "$@"
       do
          p="$p"$'\n'"$i"    # Append
       done
       echo "$p"             # No need -e
    }

    var="a b c"
    p=$( embed_newline $var )  # Do not use double quotes "$var"
    echo "$p"
   ```
3. Using `echo -e` to convert `\n` to a new line

   ```
    p="${var1}\n${var2}"
    echo -e "${p}"
   ```

   `echo -e` interprets the two characters `"\n"` as a new line.

   ```
    var="a b c"
    first_loop=true
    for i in $var
    do
       p="$p\n$i"            # Append
       unset first_loop
    done
    echo -e "$p"             # Use -e
   ```

   Avoid extra leading newline

   ```
    var="a b c"
    first_loop=1
    for i in $var
    do
       (( $first_loop )) &&  # "((...))" is bash specific
       p="$i"            ||  # First -> Set
       p="$p\n$i"            # After -> Append
       unset first_loop
    done
    echo -e "$p"             # Use -e
   ```

   Using a function

   ```
    embed_newline()
    {
       local p="$1"
       shift
       for i in "$@"
       do
          p="$p\n$i"         # Append
       done
       echo -e "$p"          # Use -e
    }

    var="a b c"
    p=$( embed_newline $var )  # Do not use double quotes "$var"
    echo "$p"
   ```

   ⚠ Inserting `"\n"` in a string is not enough to insert a new line:
   `"\n"` are just two characters.

**The output is the same for all**

```
a
b
c
```

Special thanks to contributors of this answer: [kevinf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1170023), [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817), [l0b0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96588), [Dolda2000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9139569/938111) and [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9140181/938111).

---

- See also [BinaryZebra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32802422/938111), providing many details.
- [Abhijeet Rastogi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9139537/938111) and [Dimitry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30298374/938111) explain how to avoid the `for` loop in the above [Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) snippets.

Comment: This doesn't actually embed newlines, it embeds `\n`, which the `echo -e` converts to newlines as it prints.  Depending on your actual goal, this may or may not do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much @GordonDavisson. You are right! I have then updated my answer to insert a real new lines. To thank you I have upvoted a very good answer from you. Cheers. See you ;-)

Comment: You've got a missing double quote; the third last code line should be `p="$p"$'\n'"$i"`

Comment: Yep @l0b0, you have very good eagle eyes ;-)  Next time I will help you to improve your answer :-D Thanks

Comment: This prepends the output with an extra newline!

Comment: @kevinf Thank you very much, I have just updated (extended) this four-years-old answer! Cheers :-)

Comment: # adding trailing newline, if value exists #
if [ -n "$configs" ]; then configs="$configs\n"; fi
# Appending a new value #
configs="$configs$newconfig"
# two Liner #
echo -e "$configs"

Comment: Even if this embeds a real newline in p, you'll have a hard time to actually print those with echo! At least, that doesn't work with my bash. For example: echo first > file; echo second >> file; var="$(cat file)"; echo $var; just prints "first second". But var DOES contain a new line (which you can see with: IFS=$'\n'; for f in $var; do echo ":$f:"; done).

Comment: Hi @CarloWood. Add the surrounding double quotes in `echo "$var"` and you will see the newline. Full test is: `echo first > file; echo second >> file; var="$(cat file)"; echo "$var"`. When double quote is missing, bash interprets the newline as a separator between two command line arguments: `first` and `second`. When you use the surrounding double quotes, bash understand there is a single command line argument: `$var` (that argument contains the newline). Is it clear? Have fun. Cheers

Comment: Ah... you're right. My problem was not adding double quotes when printing the variable :/. Thanks.

Comment: echo -e "script\nhere" | python3 saved me a lot of pain, many thanks.

Comment: IMHO the first option should be removed

Comment: Thank you @CervEd. I have just rephrased the `echo -e` idea and moved it down, with a ⚠ notice. I think this is better. Do you suggest to go further?

Comment: @oHo A solution using `printf` instead of `echo` is probably preferable

Answer (score 34):

The trivial solution is to put those newlines where you want them.

```
var="a
b
c"
```

Yes, that's an assignment wrapped over multiple lines.

However, you will need to double-quote the value when interpolating it, otherwise the shell will split it on whitespace, effectively turning each newline into a single space (and also expand any wildcards).

```
echo "$p"
```

Generally, you should double-quote all variable interpolations unless you specifically desire the behavior described above.

Comment: For more on proper quoting, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable

Comment: not working for me macOS Catalina, echo prints it all on one line echo -e or just echo.  :(.

Comment: @DeanHiller Again, the problem is with the quoting, not the assignment. You need `echo "$p"`, not `echo $p`. (In `zsh` you don't even need the quoting. And probably never use `echo -e`; prefer `printf` for anything where basic `echo` is too crude.)

Answer (score 15):

Try `echo $'a\nb'`.

If you want to store it in a variable and then use it with the newlines intact, you will have to quote your usage correctly:

```
var=$'a\nb\nc'
echo "$var"
```

Or, to fix your example program literally:

```
var="a b c"
for i in $var; do
    p="`echo -e "$p\\n$i"`"
done
echo "$p"
```

Comment: The `$'variable'` syntax is very convenient, but I don't believe it is portable to other shells.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Why do we have to escape \n ?

Comment: @abc: That depends on which escape you mean. If you mean the final, `echo "$p"`, it's because the shell would otherwise interpret the newlines as simple parameter separators, pass `a`, `b` and `c` to `echo` as three different parameters, and `echo` would then join them with spaces. When you quote `$p`, its exact contents are passed intact as one single parameter.

Comment: perfect, I think from `info echo` we can see all possible escaped chars to use like `var=$'\n'`, thanks!

Comment: Using `echo -e` inside backquotes is just crazy overcomplicated. If you have a newline in a variable `nl=$'\n'` you can just interpolate it `p=$p$nl$i` but even simpler, just put a literal newline in there in the first place.

Answer (score 14):

There are three levels at which a newline could be inserted in a variable.
Well ..., technically four, but the first two are just two ways to write the newline in code.

#### 1.1. At creation.

The most basic is to create the variable with the newlines already.
We write the variable value in code with the newlines already inserted.

```sh
$ var="a
> b
> c"
$ echo "$var"
a
b
c
```

Or, inside script code:

```sh
var="a
b
c"
```

Yes, that means writing <kbd>Enter</kbd> where needed in the code.

#### 1.2. Create using shell quoting.

The sequence <kbd>$</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> is a special shell expansion in Bash and Z shell.

```sh
var=$'a\nb\nc'
```

The line is parsed by the shell and expanded to « var="a<kbd>newline</kbd>b<kbd>newline</kbd>c" », which is exactly what we want the variable var to be. That will **not** work on older shells.

#### 2. Using shell expansions.

It is basically a command expansion with several commands:

1. echo -e

   ```sh
    var="$( echo -e "a\nb\nc" )"
   ```
2. The Bash and Z shell *printf '%b'*

   ```sh
    var="$( printf '%b' "a\nb\nc" )"
   ```
3. The Bash *printf -v*

   ```sh
    printf -v var '%b' "a\nb\nc"
   ```
4. Plain simple *printf* (works in most shells):

   ```sh
    var="$( printf 'a\nb\nc' )"
   ```

#### 3. Using shell execution.

All the commands listed in the second option could be used to expand the value of a variable, if that var contains special characters.

So, all we need to do is get those values inside the variable and execute some command to show:

```sh
var="a\nb\nc"                 # var will contain the characters \n not a newline.

echo -e "$var"                # use echo.
printf "%b" "$var"            # use bash %b in printf.
printf "$var"                 # use plain printf.
```

Note that *printf* is somewhat unsafe if the variable value is controlled by an attacker.

Answer (score 9):

There isn’t any need to use a *for* loop.

You can benefit from Bash parameter expansion functions:

```
var="a b c";
var=${var// /\\n};
echo -e $var
a
b
c
```

or just use tr:

```
var="a b c"
echo $var | tr " " "\n"
a
b
c
```

Comment: Re *"for cycle"*: Do you mean *"for loop"*?

Comment: yes, i mean for loop. Fixed my "typo"

Comment: This is the simplest solution. But I used a pipe | instead since the space is often needed

Answer (score 3):

`sed` solution:

```
echo "a b c" | sed 's/ \+/\n/g'
```

Result:

```
a
b
c
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var="a b c"
for i in $var
do
   p=`echo -e "$p"'\n'$i`
done
echo "$p"
```

The solution was simply to protect the inserted newline with a "" during current iteration when variable substitution happens.