# bash localization won't work with multilines strings (with strong syntax or through `eval`)

Tags: bash, localization

There is a nice feature in bash, about localization (language translation):

```
TEXTDOMAIN=coreutils
LANG=fr_CH.utf8
echo $"system boot"
démarrage système
```

(**Nota:** For this work, `fr_CH.utf8` was already *generated* on your system... Else you may try with your own locale... or install `locales` and generate one.)

**The problem:**

But if this work fine with simple strings, when string contain a `\n` (or worst: a backtick `` ` `` things are more complicated:

```
echo $"Written by %s, %s, %s,\nand %s.\n"
Written by %s, %s, %s,\nand %s.\n
```

This is not attended answer.

(**Nota2:** For this work, *exact* message has to be prepared in `.mo` message file, in this sample/test, I use existant `coreutils.mo` files, which could be *unformated* with the command `msgunfmt`.)

At all, the only way I've found to do the translation is:

```
eval echo \$\"$'Written by %s, %s, %s,\nand %s.\n'\"
Écrit par %s, %s, %s,
et %s.
```

or

```
msg=$'Written by %s, %s, %s,\nand %s.\n'
eval echo \$\""$msg"\"
Écrit par %s, %s, %s,
et %s.
```

(You could see two double quotes... not very sexy...)

And finally I could:

```
WRITTERS=(Hans Pierre Jackob Heliott)
eval printf \$\""$msg"\" ${WRITTERS[@]}
Écrit par Hans, Pierre, Jackob,
et Heliott.
```

But as I've heard recently that *eval is evil*... ;-)

In fact, I don't have problem with an `eval` that's run with *only hard coded part*, but I would appreciate a way to keep this eval out and to write this kind of part in a more *natural* or *readable* manner.

At all @techno 's answer let me see that my first idea is something *dangerous* as if `WRITTERS` contain some `;ls`, for sample...

**Edit:** So question is:

*How could I keep this `eval` out and/or write this in a more sexy fashion*

**Nota:**

```
$ printf "I use bash %s on Debian %s\n" $BASH_VERSION $(</etc/debian_version)
I use bash 4.1.5(1)-release on Debian 6.0.6
```

Comment: ... *I would appreciate a way to keep this eval out* sound not really as a question, but it is.

Comment: Ah OK. For `\n`, try `echo -e`. It is still not very clear what exactly is being asked in other parts of the question. Why are you using `echo` at all? What's wrong with `printf $"message key" $var1 $var2`?

Comment: @n.m. I complain that `$"$msg"` will work fine only if `$msg` don't contain a `\n`. If so, need to write ugly thing like `eval... \$\""$msg"\"`...

Comment: I'd suggest trying the help-bash mailing list. This is a feature that's rarely used both because it's obscure, and because of security bugs. Even people that do a lot of scripting don't tend to use it.

Comment: Aha, it's more clear now.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139401/trying-to-embed-newline-in-a-variable-in-bash

Comment: @n.m.I don't have problem with *embed newline in a variable in bash*! I have problem with *bash localized translation* with `$"..."`! Take a look at `man gettext` and `man bash` about `$"` (not `$''`).

Comment: @ormaaj: I've searched about infos through the web and at *gnu.org* but didn't find anything! If you have some links, arging your mean,your remark could become constructive. If else, I now `it's obscure`, there are no more than 5 lines in manpage and approx 10 in the Bash Reference Manual!

Comment: What am I doing wrong? http://pastie.org/pastes/5614753/text

Comment: You have to compile russian locales with utf-8 in order for this work; under Debian hit: `dpkg-reconfigure locales`.

Comment: @tijagi You have to separate by a semi-colon `LANG=ru_RU ; echo $"..."` !

Comment: Uhm… I got it now. But this requires the script to have permission for execute, so it wouldn’t change the environment LANG. And I wonder why the inline LANG setting doesn’t work. BTW in ABS guide descibed only one way to get rid of eval using gettext in a subshell, this was probably used somewhere below, so I just post the link to source http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/localization.html

Comment: Ah, stupid me, inline setting in case of localizing a script is terrible, right.

Comment: @tijagi Yes. the problem is that work, but not well while there is linebreak in strings, and that won't work when backticks are presents. Take a look at myself's answer. There is a full not-well-working-but-working-with-readable-errors sample.

Answer (score 6):

I've played a little bit with this feature and this is what I came up with: you can include the newline verbatim as:

```
$ echo $"Written by %s.
> "
Écrit par %s.
$
```

In a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

message=$"Written by %s.
"

printf "$message" Gniourf
```

This script will output:

```
Écrit par Gniourf.
```

Ok, this is not really an answer, but it might help a little bit (at least, we're not using the evil `eval`).

Personal remark: I find this feature really clunky!

Comment: Yes, thank, I've seen that too, but as you said: *this is not really -the- answer* ;-) But +1 as your way of storing and re-using`$message` is cleaner as what I've already tested. (Initial idea was using bash associative array for storing all messages, so I could imagine a nice way of doing that with your syntax.)

Comment: ...cleaner and more efficient... if all message have to be printed at least on time or more; Your way run translation when setting variable, when mine run translation when used... More or less, depending on what, when and how...

Comment: You can probably mix `$"..."` and `$'...'` for the desired effect. `msg=$'Written by %s.\n'; echo $"$msg"`

Comment: @tripleee And what if message contain backticks?  Try: `msg="$(msgunfmt /usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo | sed -ne '/missing character class/s/^.* "\(.*\)"/\1/p')"`

Comment: @tripleee (copy) Thanks to everyone. (My bounty will go to gniourf_gniourf unless best answer in 8 hours. But thanks to techno too, I like your lPrintf! )

Answer (score 3):

If using `eval` is bad with arbitrary variables, there is a way to do this *only when called/needed*, in running `eval` only on message part:

```
function lPrintf() {
    local sFormat="$(
        eval 'echo $"'"${1}"'"'.
    )"
    shift
    printf "${sFormat%.}" $@
}

lPrintf "system boot"
démarrage système

lPrintf  $'Written by %s, %s, %s,\nand %s.\n' techno moi lui-même bibi
Écrit par techno, moi, lui-même,
et bibi.
```

( The dot at end of translated string ensure that whole string, including leading line-break, where passed to variable `sFormat`. They will be dropped with `${sFormat%.}` )

Comment: Nice way to limit use of `eval`. And to make them a little more sexy! +1, but there is an `eval` anyway...

Comment: Thanks to everyone. (My bounty will go to gniourf_gniourf unless best answer in 8 hours. But thanks to techno too, I like your lPrintf! )

Answer (score 2):

OK I think finally got it right.

```
iprintf() {
    msg="$2"
    domain="$1"
    shift
    shift
    imsg=$(gettext -ed "$domain" "$msg" ; echo EOF)
    imsg="${imsg%EOF}"
    printf "$imsg" "$@"
}
```

Usage example:

```
LANG=fr_CH.utf8 iprintf coreutils "If FILE is not specified, use %s.  %s as FILE is common.\n\n" foo bar
```

Comment: Yes sure, but if this let us keep `eval` *and* ugly form out, this add a *fork* and this is not as quick as invoking `$"..."`. But thank for contrib!

Comment: If you can produce **profiling data** that pinpoint this *fork* as the performance bottleneck in your system, you probably should not have written it in `bash` in the first place.

Comment: difference exist (as tiny they are). The feature exist. So if they exist why did a need to use *expensive fork*? While *each time cost* have to be reduced, I think your comment is not constructive.

Comment: More electrons are probably wasted on this thread than ever will be on all these forks...

Comment: A shell script that doesn't invoke any external programs probably shouldn't be a shell script. Note the subshell doesn't really add any cost. It's a single fork+exec either way. @n.m. I'd use local variables, or better, use the parameters directly. It's also not a very good idea to expand a variable into the first argument of printf, especially in Bash, especially when it results from calling an external program. The `-v` option can result in executing arbitrary code. Also, `shift` can take an argument to indicate the number of shifts.

Comment: @ormaaj (copy)  Thanks to everyone. (My bounty will go to gniourf_gniourf unless best answer in 8 hours. But thanks to techno too, I like your lPrintf! )

Answer (score 1):

### Simple solution for building a translation function:

```
f() {
    eval 'local msg=$"'"${1//[\"\$\`]}"\"
    shift
    printf "${msg}" "$@"
}
```

Test:

```
TEXTDOMAIN=coreutils
LANG="fr_CH.utf8"
f system boot
démarrage système

f $'Written by %s, %s, %s,\nand %s.\n' Athos Portos Aramis Shreck
Écrit par Athos, Portos, Aramis
et Shreck.
```

#### But as I prefer setting variables instead of forking function:

```
f() {
    eval 'local msg=$"'"${1//[\"\$\`]}"\"
    local -n variable=$2
    shift 2
    printf -v variable "$msg" "$@"
}
```

Then

```
f $'Written by %s, %s, %s,\nand %s.\n' string Huey Dewey Louie Batman
echo ${string@Q}
$'Écrit par Huey, Dewey, Louie\net Batman.\n'

echo "$string"
Écrit par Huey, Dewey, Louie
et Batman.
```

#### Or even better as a full translation function:

```
f() {
    local store=false OPTIND OPTARG OPTERR varname
    while getopts 'd:v:' opt ;do
        case $opt in
            d ) local TEXTDOMAIN=$OPTARG ;;
            v ) varname=$OPTARG ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND-1))
    eval 'local msg=$"'"${1//[\"\$\`]}"\"
    shift
    printf ${varname+-v} $varname "$msg" "$@"
}
```

Then

```
f -d libc -v string "Permission denied"
echo $string
Permission non accordée

f -d coreutils $'Written by %s, %s, %s,\nand %s.\n' Riri Fifi Loulou Georges
Écrit par Riri, Fifi, Loulou
et Georges.
```

### Old answer (Jan 2013)

Well, there is my self answer:

This seem not well implemented now. Work in many situations, but, while

```
echo "$(gettext 'missing character class name `[::]'\')"
caractère de nom de classe « [::] » manquant
```

work simply, the same string seem impossible to translate using this *bashism*:

```
echo $"missing character class name `[::]'"
>
```

the console stay *locked* (waiting for such an end of string) adding ``" ` would immerse bash in a complex interpretation process :->>

```
> `"
bash: command substitution: line 1: Caractère de fin de fichier (EOF) prématuré lors de la recherche du « ' » correspondant
bash: command substitution: line 2: Erreur de syntaxe : fin de fichier prématurée
missing character class name
```

And, of course:

```
echo $"missing character class name \`[::]'"
missing character class name `[::]'
```

make no translation. :-p

While translating this string containing **two** backticks work **finely**:

```
echo $"%s}: integer required between `{' and `}'"
%s} : entier requis entre « { » et « } »
```

There is a script where you may see some of mine unsuccessfull trys.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Localized tests"
export TEXTDOMAIN=coreutils
export LANG=fr_CH.UTF-8
export WRITTERS=(Athos Portos Aramis Dartagnan\ Le\ Beau)

echo '#First method# whitout eval'

declare -A MyMessages;
MyMessages[sysReboot]=$"system boot"
MyMessages[writtenBy]=$"Written by %s, %s, %s,
and %s.
"
MyMessages[intReq]=$"%s}: integer required between `{' and `}'"
MyMessages[trClass]=$"when translating, the only character classes that may appear in
string2 are `upper' and `lower'"
# MyMessages[missClass]=$"missing character class name `[::]'" 

for msgIdx in ${!MyMessages[@]} ;do
    printf "\n--- Test chain '%s' ---\n" $msgIdx
    case $msgIdx in
    writ* )
        printf "${MyMessages[$msgIdx]}\n" "${WRITTERS[@]}"
        ;;
    intReq )
        printf "ARRAY{${MyMessages[$msgIdx]}\n" NaN
        ;;
    * )
        printf "${MyMessages[$msgIdx]}\n"
        ;;
    esac
  done

echo $'###\n#Second method# whith limited eval'
unset MyMessages;

declare -A MyMessages;

lPrintf() {
    local sFormat="$(
        eval 'echo $"'"${1}"'"'.
    )"
    shift
    printf "${sFormat%.}" "$@"
}

MyMessages[sysReboot]="system boot"
MyMessages[writtenBy]=$'Written by %s, %s, %s,\nand %s.\n'
MyMessages[intReq]="%s}: integer required between \`{' and \`}'"
MyMessages[trClass]="when translating, the only character classes that "
MyMessages[trClass]+=$'may appear in\nstring2 '
MyMessages[trClass]+="are \`upper' and \`lower'"
MyMessages[missClass]="missing character class name \`[::]'"

for msgIdx in ${!MyMessages[@]} ;do
    printf "\n--- Test chain '%s' ---\n" $msgIdx
    case $msgIdx in
    writ* )
        lPrintf "${MyMessages[$msgIdx]}" "${WRITTERS[@]}"
        ;;
    intReq )
        lPrintf "${MyMessages[$msgIdx]}" NaN
        ;;
    * )
        lPrintf "${MyMessages[$msgIdx]}"
        ;;
    esac
  done
```

and his output:

```
Localized tests
#First method# whitout eval

--- Test chain 'trClass' ---
à la traduction, les seules classes de caractères qui peuvent apparaître
dans string2 sont « upper » ou « lower »

--- Test chain 'intReq' ---
ARRAY{NaN} : entier requis entre « { » et « } »

--- Test chain 'sysReboot' ---
démarrage système

--- Test chain 'writtenBy' ---
Écrit par Athos, Portos, Aramis,
et Dartagnan Le Beau.

###
#Second method# whith limited eval

--- Test chain 'trClass' ---
à la traduction, les seules classes de caractères qui peuvent apparaître
dans string2 sont « upper » ou « lower »
--- Test chain 'missClass' ---
./localized.sh: eval: line 44: Caractère de fin de fichier (EOF) prématuré lors de la recherche du « ` » correspondant
./localized.sh: eval: line 45: Erreur de syntaxe : fin de fichier prématurée

--- Test chain 'intReq' ---
NaN} : entier requis entre « { » et « } »
--- Test chain 'sysReboot' ---
démarrage système
--- Test chain 'writtenBy' ---
Écrit par Athos, Portos, Aramis,
et Dartagnan Le Beau.
```

If anyone could help my to remove comments and/or error message in this script!? ... (in less then 8 hours?!)

At all, thanks to everyone. (My bounty will go to @gniourf_gniourf unless best answer in 8 hours. But thanks to @techno too, I like your lPrintf! )

Answer (score 0):

#### Talking you out of it

Fundamentally you should probably be not concerned about this issue, because C and Bash are different in how `printf` works: C's `printf` does not translate backslash escapes, while the Bash one does. So in an ideal world, you should really only be doing is just `printf $"%s, %s,\n%s" some thing more` and having the template string retain the raw backslash escape (so it might look like `msgid "%s, %s,\\n%s"` in the po-file).

As you have already realized, the `$""` construct also disallows the use of msgids invalid to bash's double-quotation syntax. There simply is no way to use this entry:

```
msgid "`"
msgstr "« "
```

and by stripping these problematic characters away it only masks the problem. (Again, it's fine for bash, because you would've been writing `` echo $"\`" `` and `` msgid "\\`" ``).

On the other hand, there really is [good reason to not use the `$""` construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/bash.html). The construct allows translators to run arbitrary commands, creating one more real level of insecurity compared to `eval`. Using the [gettext.sh functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/sh.html) is free from the problem, as any variable substitution is handled by a separate `envsubst` program. And it also lets you use `$''` as much as you like.