# How to tell bash to get gettext .mo file from custom location?

Tags: linux, bash, gettext, msgfmt

I am creating a bash script for a very specific project, and the strings must be translatable.

I have successfully followed the following tutorial: gettext support for bash scripts:
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/098

However, part of the tutorial asks to run the msgfmt command to generate compiled .mo files for each language. To make it work, I had to run the command as root and the .mo files are saved under /usr/share/locale/(lang)/LC_MESSAGES.

I'd like the .mo files to be saved in a sub-directory relative to the bash script, which is easy enough. **But then, when the script is run, bash has to know what is must look for the .mo files in the appropriate, custom location.**

How to achieve this?

What I am trying to do is to have the whole project, together with .pot and .mo files, self-contained and  be able to update the translations without having to use sudo.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027030/bash-localization-wont-work-with-multilines-strings-with-strong-syntax-or-thro

Comment: What have you tried? Please past some samples of code tested and error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you play with environment variable `TEXTDOMAINDIR`

You could maybe find more informations in `info` pages than in `man` page:

```
info gettext
```

or

```
info gettext 'Variable Index'
```

Comment: Thanks. That's probably it. I'll look into it and report back.

Comment: @augustin Did you make it work somehow?

Comment: @JānisElmeris Have a look at [bash localization won't work with multilines strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14027030/1765658)