# Newline in bashscript variable

Tags: bash, variables, unix, newline

I have the code:

```
for file in *
    do
      list="$list""$file "`cat $file | wc -l | sort -k1`$'\n'
   done

echo $list
```

This outputs a list like `fileA 10 fileB 20 fileC 30`.

I thought it should output:

```
fileA 10
fileB 20
fileC 30
```

I need the output to follow the latter as I then want to cycle through the `$list`variable one line at a time and perform operations.

Could someone please help me out here?

Thank you.

Comment: Try `echo "$list"` instead. If you don't include the quotes the arguments will be split on whitespace and echo will separate them with a single space.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to embed newline in a variable in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139401/trying-to-embed-newline-in-a-variable-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does have the new-line characters in the variable. when a variable is used outside of quotes it splits it into multiple arguments separated by whitespace.

what you want is `echo "$list"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
 for file in *
  do
     count=$(cat "$file" | wc -l)
     list="$list$file $count\n"
  done

echo -e $list

-e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes
```

Comment: Or `wc -l <"$file"` to avoid that pesky UUOC.

Comment: Exactly, `count=$(wc -l < "$file")` is better, +1 triplee