# why is a bash variable containing \n not equal to its copy?

Tags: bash, variables, if-statement, newline

After setting:

```
var1="a\nb"
var2="$var1"
```

I expect `$var1` and `$var2` to be equal; however:

```
[[ $var1 == $var2 ]] && echo yes || echo no
```

returns `no`. Why is that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to quote to perform the string comparison:

```
[[ "$var1" == "$var2" ]]
```

So this works:

```
$ var1="a\nb"
$ var2="$var1"
$ [[ "$var1" == "$var2" ]] && echo yes || echo no
yes
```

#### Why is this happening?

From the comments, [chepner indicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782601/why-is-a-bash-variable-containing-n-not-equal-to-its-copy#comment42142660_26782654):

> Without the quotes, $var2 is interpreted as a pattern, not a string,
>   and the \n is treated as a regular n.

Comment: `echo "$var1"` displays `a\nb`. Why it fails to display a newline?

Comment: `bash` doesn't interpret backslash escapes by default. You need to use `echo -n "$var1"` instead.

Comment: @AvinashRaj `\n` does not suffice. You need something like `var1="a"$'\n'"b"`. See [Trying to embed newline in a variable in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9139891/1983854) for more info.

Comment: Without the quotes, `$var2` is interpreted as a pattern, not a string, and the `\n` is treated as a regular `n`, so `[[ anb == $var2 ]]` would succeed.

Comment: @chepner thanks a lot (as always) for the deeper explanation. I added your comment into the answer.

Comment: Only the rhs of `==` needs to be quoted: `[[ $var1 == "$var2" ]]` is enough. From the manual: _When the `==` and `!=` operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below in Pattern Matching._

Comment: ah - after reading [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427872/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash) I thought that would not be needed. Thanks.