# Unable to Logon bteq on linux using script

Tags: linux, teradata

I am unable to log on `bteq` on linux using script, what am I doing wrong?

```
echo ".LOGMECH LDAP\n.LOGON eiwd/${USER_ID},${PASSWORD};\n.LOGOFF;\n.EXIT" > $UAT_COUNT/test_spool_bteq.sql

bteq < $UAT_COUNT/test_spool_bteq.sql > $UAT_COUNT/test_spool_log.log
```

**OUTPUT**

> Error: Invalid command syntax.
>   Extra text found starting at '\n.LOGON eiwd/u431311,mum'.
>   *** Warning: You must log on before sending SQL requests.
>
>   *** Warning: EOF on INPUT stream.

Comment: You may need a semi-colon after the .LOGMECH command and the \n doesn't seem to be translating in the echo redirection.

Comment: you can try `echo -e` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139401/trying-to-embed-newline-in-a-variable-in-bash and what is in your created sql file?