# How to append a newline to a variable in sh?

Tags: shell

```
var  = "a common string \n $var"
```

I am passing this var to some other method and I am printing var in that other method.i am not able to edit that other method. So `echo -e` and `printf` statements cannot be used by me. But I need that \n to be printed as new line instead of that exact literal.

Comment: `var  = "a common string \n $var"` is not a correct way to assign a variable. Also, how are you printing the var in the other method?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.I don't know how to append a common string followed by a new line to the existing variable and that is my question. In that new method we are just using echo statement only

Comment: See: [How can I have a newline in a string in sh?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3005963/1983854) or [Trying to embed newline in a variable in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9139401/1983854).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are setting `var` in shell script you can actually use `printf` as follows:

```
var=$(printf "a common string\n%s" "$var")
```

or, in newer `bash`

```
printf -v var "a common string\n%s" "$var"
```

If your shell supports the `$'…'` construct, you can do this instead:

```
var=$'a common string \n'"$var"
```

Answer (score 0):

Treat the variable as a list with '\n' delimiter so you can go over it in a loop and print each item on it in a new line, something like:

```
for item in $var; do 
  echo $item
done
```