# \n doesn't work in linux file

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, newline

I have a bash script and I have a string with some `\n`:

```
interfaces="auto lo\niface lo inet loopback\n\n..."
```

Then I try to write this into the interfaces file like so:

```
sudo bash -c "echo -e $interfaces > /etc/network/interfaces"
```

I use `-e` to display the `\n`'s but if I open the file it doesn't show right but if I just output it to the terminal it works:

`auto loniface lo inet loopbacknn...`

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139401/trying-to-embed-newline-in-a-variable-in-bash

Comment: @KenY-N That won't work when the string gets substituted into the `bash -c` argument. `bash` will see it as a literal newline, which is a command delimiter.

Comment: @KenY-N I mean if I `echo` it to the terminal it works but not in the file. I'll try the solution of @Barmar now.

Comment: Hmm, given the answer below, I've changed my mind about it being a dup - the extra level of quotes is missing from the linked dup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put quotes around the variable.

```
sudo bash -c "echo -e '$interfaces' > /etc/network/interfaces"
```

Outside of a quoted string, `\n` gets replaced with `n`.

Comment: @joepd No, that's not correct.

Comment: Worked for me thanks!