# Start bash script with SSH

Tags: bash, ssh

I use a bash script which makes an ssh connection to other machines and executes scripts (which are stored on those machine).

1. SSH to master to execute script 1
2. SSH to master to execute script 2
3. SSH to master to execute script 3
4. SSH to node1 to execute script 1
   etc..

Now my question is: Will the execution of script 2 on the master start before the script 1 (which takes 30 seconds) is finished? Will they run at the same time?

Comment: Like any other command, `ssh` runs until it's done, unless you specifically run it in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be dependent on how your bash script on your machine (which does the SSH connection to the servers) and the scripts on those servers works.

For example: The following commands are completely procedural and not parallelized so long as scripts 1, 2, and 3 are procedural as well and do not fork work into the background before exiting (i.e. All work is done when the script exits)

```
ssh master 'script1' 
ssh master 'script2' 
ssh master 'script3'
```

This can be simplified as

```
ssh master 'script1; script2; script3'
```

You could parallelize the work by forking these scripts to the background, thus running scripts 1, 2 and 3 at the same time.

```
ssh master 'script1 &; script2 &; script3 &'
```

Again, just make sure that your scripts don't fork work into the background themselves and exit before the work is done

Answer (score 1):

I'm just giving here a more detailed answer than @tripleee...

Will execute script2 after the completion of script1:

```sh
ssh master script1
ssh master script2
```

You could do the same in one connection:

```sh
ssh master 'script1 ; script2'
```

If you want them to run at the same time:

```sh
ssh master 'script1 &; script2 &'
```

To cite the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

> If a command is terminated by the control operator `&`, the shell executes the command in the *background* in a subshell.

There are posts (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412238/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-ssh-and-run-multiple-commands-in-bash) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950168/multiple-commands-on-remote-machine-using-shell-script)) on how to run multiples commands in one connection.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Compare

```
sleep 10
date

sleep 10 &
date
```